# Custom JS not loaded when JS aggregation is enabled

Tags: 7, css-js-aggregation

I have a couple of custom JS files in my theme that works as they should.
Except that when I enable the JS aggregation (in Config -> Performance) to speed things up these JS functions stop working, and the files are not even loaded, as far as I can see (I have tried to search for keywords in Firebug script tab to see if the functions are still being executed). I have chosen to simply include them in the theme's info file.

So my question is... must I add my custom JS files in some other way in order for the JS aggregation to include them?

Comment: Nope, nothing else you need to do. As long as they're in the format `scripts[] = path/to/script.js` in the .info file that's all Drupal needs. Just make you clear all caches (including page cache) so that the newly aggregated files are rebuilt, and actually linked from the html

Comment: Did you check to see if other Javascript functions are working? Check the console for errors, sometimes errors will prevent the functions from working.

Comment: _I have tried to search for keywords in Firebug script tab to see if the functions are still being executed_ Aggregation also minifies the scripts, so variables get renamed and such. It is no guarantee your script is not in there.

Comment: @Neograph734 That was an option in Drupal 6, but not in Drupal 7 - usually that functionality gets added with the AdvAgg module. No JS gets minified using core aggregation alone

Comment: @Clive Oh really... I always assumed it would do that to make it even more efficient.

Comment: Yeah @Neograph734, there were some problems with the D6 version if memory serves - it could occasionally ruin the whole thing and not even basic jQuery would work for a site. Because of that I think they decided to pull it out and let contrib handle it

Comment: @Clive Ah got it. It makes sense. I did check it before posting my comment, but the one file I tried in fact contained an already minified library... :(

Comment: Hi, and thanks for all the suggestions. I have done some further digging, and it turns out that other custom js files, that I added in one of my custom modules, actually are included after aggregation. But not the ones added in the theme... I keep digging... (and I can confirm now that they are not minified)

Comment: Hello again. Instead of adding the js files in the theme's info file, I added them in template.php with `drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme'....`  and after that it works! I know that I should be able to use the info file, but my problem is solved, so I am happy. Thanks again.